# Is there an equivalent for "NameValueCollection" and "CultureInfo" class in java?

Tags: java, c#

I'm translating a code which is in c# and I want to know if there is an equivalent in java.

I searched on internet but didn't find an answer.

```
private NameValueCollection m_objCommands;
private CultureInfo m_objCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: Maybe a Map for NameValueCollection? And maybe Locale for CultureInfo?

Answer (score 1):

Definition of `NameValueCollection` is

> Represents a collection of associated String keys and String values that can be accessed either with the key or with the index.

So it can be denoted by `Map<String, String>` in Java. Documentation for the same is present [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Definition of `CultureInfo` is

> Provides information about a specific culture (called a locale for unmanaged code development).

So it can be denoted by `Locale` in Java. Documentation for the same is present [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).