# Is there an equivelent of Path.IsPathRooted() in java?

Tags: java, c#

I barely understand the function IsPathRooted() and I'll like to know how could I code an equivalent in Java.
Here's the function I have to translate.

```
private string EnsureAbsolutePath(string strFileName){
    string strReturn = strFileName;
    if (Path.IsPathRooted(strFileName) == false)
        strReturn = GetAbsolutePathFromRelativeFileName(strFileName);
    return strReturn;
}
```

Comment: This is the second C# to Java question you've [asked in the last hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456500/is-there-an-equivalent-for-namevaluecollection-and-cultureinfo-class-in-java), perhaps you should go and do some learning on the languages before asking here?

Comment: I do but I still don't understand while when I asked here I had a clear answer.

Comment: [`Path.GetRoot()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getRoot--) : _"Returns the root component of this path as a Path object, or null if this path does not have a root component."_

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is the Java 'getParent' method:

```
if (Paths.get(strFileName).getParent() != null)
{
    strReturn = GetAbsolutePathFromRelativeFileName(strFileName);
}
```

Comment: Your if condition test is the opposite of the original C#

Comment: @Palamino: Are you sure? The original test is against 'false'.

Comment: The original if condition is basically saying "if NOT a rooted path then" where your if condition is saying "if a rooted path then"

Comment: @Palamino:  Please read the condition again carefully: ...getParent() == null

Comment: Yes, I know.  A path with no parent is a root path.  The original if condition is poorly written because it takes a boolean value and compares it to false, which essentially negates the boolean value.  Rewriting the original statement as if(!Path.IsPathRooted(strFileName)) would make the difference from yours more obvious.  Your statement is TRUE if the path has no parent, aka a Root path.  The original statement is FALSE if the path is a Root path.

Comment: @Palamino: Right - took a while for that to sink in - I've corrected my answer.  Thanks.